# Display multi images with condition

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I try to display a part of gallery's photo=> this is result when i did the `search action`.  This result have `avatar` like a `picture` and `infomation` like `username or email`.

I create `Photo.java` like `child` of `Users.java` in relationship `@ManytoOne`

Here is my code :

Photo.java----

```
@Entity
public class Photo extends Model{
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String path;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    public Users user;

}
```

Users.java-----

```
@Entity
public class Users extends Model{
        @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String username;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String email;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
        public List<Photo> photo = new ArrayList<Photo>();

    public Users(){}

    public Users(String username,String email,String password){
        this.username=username;
        this.email=email;
        this.password=password;
    }
}
```

Search.java -----

```
public static Result search(){
            DynamicForm form = form().bindFromRequest();
            String name = form.get("name");
            Finder<Long, Users> find = new Finder<Long, Users>(Long.class, Users.class);
            List<Users> users = find.where().like("username", '%'+ name +'%').findList();


            if (form.get("name")=="" || users.isEmpty() || users==null){
              return ok(search_again.render()); 
          }
          else{       
        return ok (search_result.render(users));
          }
    }
```

search_result.scala.html----

```
@(users : List[Users])
@main(nav= "search"){
    <h3>Result</h3>

    <a href="@routes.Search.blank"><input class="button" type="button" value="Back to Search"></a>
    <a href="@routes.Application.index"><input class="button" type="button" value="Back to Home"></a>

    <p>Found @users.size() result(s) : </p>

    <div class="sresult">
        @for(user <- users){

        <div id="sresult">
        <div id="haha"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("upload/"+user.photo.path)"></div>
//Error here.  Why "user.photo.path" not working ?
            <p>
               @user.username</a></br>
               @user.password</a></br>
               @user.email</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        }

    </div>
}
```

Why "user.photo.path" not working ? any ideal in my case ?

Comment: Likely because photo is a List<Photo> rather than an actual Photo object.

Comment: i think so. and How can i solved that ?